# Issue a warning when a shared pointer is captured by a "all-by-reference" capture

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

Consider a (simplified) function like this:

```
void foo(const Bar& bar)
{
  const auto fun = [&] () { some_other_api(bar); };

  put_somewhere(fun);
}
```

This works perfectly fine until the other API is refactored and now expects a shared_ptr. A developer runs throug all the compiler errors and changes foo into:

```
void foo(std::shared_ptr<const Bar> bar)
{
  const auto fun = [&] () { some_other_api(bar); };

  put_somewhere(fun);
}
```

And BAAAMM the application segfaults (hopefully during testing). Now it is extremely hard to find all the places without some support from the compiler.

The issue here is that capturing all variables by reference is usually done in places where there are many variables and large functions, so this antipattern is easy to overlook. Is there a way to enforce a warning if a shared pointer is captured like this?

Comment: Is shared_ptr really different from any other type in this context?

Comment: Passing the `shared_ptr` by reference would solve this. But maybe that's not an option?

Comment: I guess the problem you are introducing by this change is not caused by using `shared_ptr`, but because you changed the argument from reference type to a value type.

Comment: Have you considered capturing the shared pointer not by reference (`[&]`), but by value (`[=]`) instead?

Comment: @Aconcagua that is precisely the point. The capture by reference is unintentional and the situation stems from that oversight.